# How to delete a image in PhotosAlbum in iOS

Tags: iphone, photo, photolibrary

In my iPhone application I am saving an image on Save button click, using the code

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(previewImg.image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);`

So, is there any way to delete last saved image through code?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Only the user can delete their photo and video assets.

Answer (score 0):

Using `UIImageView *photoImageView;` show the photo it ok then save else retake or rechoose the photo again

[see this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoLocations/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008909)